# SQL query with multiple tables, columns, values

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I'm very new to SQL, so be gentle if I write complete bullshit. I got a phpbb database, where I need to get post_topic and post_text of all topics that are in topics_track from a specific user. My unsuccessful query (again, with basically no knowledge of SQL) is the following:

```
SELECT post_subject, post_text
FROM phpbb_posts
WHERE topic_id=(ALL topic_id from phpbb_topics_track where user_id='165261')
```

Can you help me get the right query?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: To make things clearer, add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
SELECT post_subject, post_text
FROM phpbb_posts
WHERE topic_id = ANY (select topic_id from phpbb_topics_track where user_id='165261');
```

or

```
SELECT post_subject, post_text
FROM phpbb_posts
WHERE topic_id IN (select topic_id from phpbb_topics_track where user_id='165261');
```